# @RequestBody used to determine which bean to autowire

Tags: java, spring

Is there any way we can condition the bean creation depending on the @RequestBody payload (or POST URL) coming in to the controller?

I have interface B and class ServiceB. ServiceB depends on B. I have configured it as such in the application Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServiceNowMediatorApplication.class, args);
}
@Bean
public B b(){
    return new BImpl();
}


@Bean
public ServiceB serviceB(B b){
    return new ServiceB(b);
}

}
```

BImpl class implements Interface B

The b object is received as the body of a POST call

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/{database}/alerts")
public class ControllerB {
  @Autowired private ServiceB serviceB;

  @Autowired
  private B b;

  @Autowired
  ControllerB(B b,ServiceB serviceB){
      this.b = b;
      this.serviceB = serviceB;
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public B dosomethingCrazy(@RequestBody BImpl bimpl)  {


      String response = serviceB.dosomethingImportant();
      return bimpl;

  }

}
```

The ServiceB class

```
@Service
public class ServiceB {


@Autowired
public B b;

@Autowired
public B getB() {
    return b;
}

@Autowired
public void setB(B b) {
    this.b = b;
}

@Autowired
public ServiceB(B b){
    this.b = b;

}
```

If I have a ServiceC class which also implements B, how can I autowire that in the controller depending on the RequestBody ?

Thanks so much!

Comment: `@RequestBody` is not defining any auto-wiring of beans. `@RequestBody` tells the MVC controller to create an instance of `BImpl` using the no-arg constructor, and then call setter methods with the values of the incoming HTTP POST request. This has nothing to do with wiring of *beans*, and your service class is certainly not involved in that process.

Comment: Also, auto-wiring occur when the Spring container starts up. How did you expect the auto-wiring to use information from the HTTP POST request body to make auto-wiring decisions, when no POST request has been received yet? The controller is a *singleton* and handles all requests for that URL, regardless of POST body content.